# Ubuntu 14.04 do not start up (latest kernel deleted)

Tags: delete

Today I did install Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS on a new PC (no dual boot!)
After fine tuning the whole day, I did delete per accident the latest sub kernel of 3.19.0-30-gen.
Now the pc do not start up at all, only the UBUNTU logo is visible.
How can I repair this problem please, perhaps with the Live-CD or other programs or things? The Live CD is that the one I can dowload from the Ubuntu  site, so to try or install Ubuntu?
Please help??!